# In algebraic equations, why does it seem one side is multiplied differently from the other?

Tags: linear-algebra

note: *I believe I have answered this question while typing it out, however I will need confirmation by another user as I am a layman in mathematics.*

I know in algebra what happens on both sides is equal. However, say we have the following equation and we want to solve for x

$$ 10/2 = x/5 $$

Step 1: multiply both sides by 5 $$ 5/1 * 10/2 = x/5 * 5 $$

Leaving the answer...
$$ 50/2 = x $$

Now why is it that the left hand side is multiplied by 5/1 and the right hand side by 5.

Should the right hand side not be $$  x/5 * 5/1 $$
which leaves $$  x5/5 $$

Ok. I think I have just answered the question typing this out, are you left with $x$ on the right hand side because the two fives cancel out?

Comment: Yes, the five cancels out..

Comment: Yes - you have indeed answered your own question. Also note that:$$\frac{5}{1}=5$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have answered this question while typing it out, however I wanted confirmation by another user as I am a layman in mathematics.

The reason why it may seem like two different operations are carried out on algebraic equations is because some mathematicians skip writing out the full operations, presuming it is known by the reader.

The two fives do in-deed cancel out, which can be seen when the algebraic equation is written in full rather than short-hand.

Comment: Thank you for writing up your own answer - it saves questions that have been answered in comments from hanging around forever in an unanswered state!

Answer (score 0):

The following are equivalent:

Method 1
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
\frac{10}{2}&=\frac{x}{5}\\
\therefore 5\times\frac{10}{2}&=5\times\frac{x}{5}\\
\therefore \frac{50}{2}&=\cancel{5}\times\frac{x}{\cancel{5}}\\
\therefore25&=x
\end{align}$$

Method 2
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
\frac{10}{2}&=\frac{x}{5}\\
\therefore \frac{5}{1}\times\frac{10}{2}&=\frac{5}{1}\times\frac{x}{5}\\
\therefore \frac{50}{2}&=\frac{\cancel{5}}{1}\times\frac{x}{\cancel{5}}\\
\therefore25&=x
\end{align}$$

Method 3
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
\frac{10}{2}&=\frac{x}{5}\\
\therefore \frac{5}{1}\times\frac{10}{2}&=5\times\frac{x}{5}\\
\therefore \frac{50}{2}&=\cancel{5}\times\frac{x}{\cancel{5}}\\
\therefore25&=x
\end{align}$$

Method 4
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
\frac{10}{2}&=\frac{x}{5}\\
\therefore 5\times\frac{10}{2}&=\frac{5}{1}\times\frac{x}{5}\\
\therefore \frac{50}{2}&=\frac{\cancel{5}}{1}\times\frac{x}{\cancel{5}}\\
\therefore25&=x
\end{align}$$